# Why does the Extbase PersistenceManager think that my object is new?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I want to update some Extbase Objects in a Scheduler Task. I'm calling the Repository to get all Objects. Then I set one Property of that object, and Try do Update it.
That throws me this Exception

> The object of type "FFPI\FfpiNodeUpdates\Domain\Model\Node" given to update must be persisted already, but is new.
>
> vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/PersistenceManager.php:237

the trace is:
0: TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
1: TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
2: FFPI\FfpiNodeUpdates\Task\NotificationTask
3: FFPI\FfpiNodeUpdates\Task\NotificationTask
4: TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Scheduler
5: TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Controller\SchedulerModuleController
...

my code can be shortened to this

```
$nodes = $this->nodeRepository->findAll()->toArray();
foreach ($nodes as $node){
    $this->myUpdateFunction($node);
}
```

```
private function myUpdateFunction(Node $node)
{
    $node->setOnline(true);
    $this->nodeRepository->update($node); // <- Gives the exception
}
```

It worked fine in 7.6 but dose not work anymore in 8.7

I tried to get the Repository with
* dependency Injection (dose not work at all)
* GeneralUtility::makeInstance() (I get the repo, but have the exception)
* objectManager->get() (I get the repo, but have the exception)

Update:
I have this problem also in version 9.5

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use the makeInstance() function only to get the Object Manager, then you should use him instead of the makeInstance() to deal with your Objects.

For your main problem, I'm not sure if it helps but you may have to use PersistanceManger->persistAll(); 
In its code, there is a comment saying: "Commits new objects and changes to objects in the current persistence session into the backend"

I hope this helps ^^

Comment: I can use Persist all only after I updated my object, otherwise it is useless. The Problem is that my object **is not new**, but the PersistenceManager claims it is new.

Comment: @kevinq Is there any solution for this? I am having this same problem.

Comment: @MithunJack yes and now. It is currently working, but I don't know what I did. You can check the code and commit history here https://github.com/freifunk-pinneberg/typo3-tx_ffpi_node_updates/blob/feature/typo3v9/Classes/Task/NotificationTask.php